# Join lines from two files

Tags: join, paste

I'm trying to combine two different files, one called `itemnum` and another called `items`.

`itemnum` contains:

```
ItemNumber
1201
1221
1320
1340
1410
```

and items contains:

```
Item
Lobby Furniture
Ballroom Specialties
Poolside Carts
Formal Dining Specials
Reservation Logs
```

I want to use `join` here right? So that the output looks like this:

```
ItemNumber:Item
1201:Lobby Furniture
1221:Ballroom Specialties
1320:Poolside Carts
1340:Formal Dining Specials
1410:Reservation Logs
```

I can't even figure out how to get them to join, let alone add the :

I tried `join itemnum items > prodinfo`, but that just gives me an empty file.

Comment: I guess you've misunderstood the `join` command. Check http://linux.die.net/man/1/join

Comment: The `join` command joins files on a *common key* (which your files do not appear to have) - if you just want to join successive lines from each file side-by-side you can use the `paste` command instead e.g. `paste -d\: itemnum items > prodinfo`

Comment: How would I add a colon? Using -d?

Answer (score 3):

As mentioned : Join requires a key column and isn't the right command for what you are looking to do.
Confirmed as @steeldriver says

```
paste -d : file1.txt file2.txt > filemerge.txt
```