# Ordering two lists separated by spaces side-by-side

Tags: shell-script, text-formatting

I made two files, foo.txt and bar.txt

foo.txt looks as such: `foo1 foo2 foo3 foo4 foo5 foo6 foo7 foo8 foo9 foo10`

And bar.txt: `bar1 bar2 bar3 bar4 bar5 bar6 bar7 bar8 bar9 bar10`

How do you then get these two text files and output them into a text file called foobar.txt, ordering them as

```
foo1 bar1
foo2 bar2
foo3 bar3
...
```

Admin stuff: I'm getting warnings about this being a duplicate question because people have suggested combining

```
foo1
foo2
foo3
foo4
foo5
```

and

```
bar1
bar2
bar3
bar4
bar5
```

Is the same process. If you have to do this instead you can find the question addressing text on new line combination here: [Link to user2120893's Question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/306787/join-lines-from-two-files)

To address editing files, with one command, of spaced items, you need to use the answer I have marked below using awk.
I kept seeing questions of 'how to combine two lists' and 'how to separate spaced lists into new line lists' but never a one line command, using awk, to separate two spaced lists by awk functions then combine them via being designated through awk. A huge thank you to Sergiy Kolodyazhnyy for finally answering my question (and only using one command to do it!). I've been looking for an answer to this for a while and an awk wizard stepped in to show us the ropes. Credit to John1024 for another great answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Decently achievable with `awk` :

```
$ awk 'NR==FNR{split($0,a);}NR!=FNR{for(i=1;i<=NF;i++) print a[i],$i}' foo.txt bar.txt
foo1 bar1
foo2 bar2
foo3 bar3
foo4 bar4
foo5 bar5
foo6 bar6
foo7 bar7
foo8 bar8
foo9 bar9
foo10 bar10
```

Answer (score 1):

Let's start with these two files:

```
$ cat foo.txt 
foo1 foo2 foo3 foo4 foo5 foo6 foo7 foo8 foo9 foo10
$ cat bar.txt 
bar1 bar2 bar3 bar4 bar5 bar6 bar7 bar8 bar9 bar10
```

To combine them together:

```
$ paste <(tr ' ' '\n' <foo.txt) <(tr ' ' '\n' <bar.txt)
foo1    bar1
foo2    bar2
foo3    bar3
foo4    bar4
foo5    bar5
foo6    bar6
foo7    bar7
foo8    bar8
foo9    bar9
foo10   bar10
```

Or:

```
$ awk -v RS='[[:space:]]+' 'FNR==NR{a[NR]=$0; next} {print a[FNR],$0}' foo.txt bar.txt
foo1 bar1
foo2 bar2
foo3 bar3
foo4 bar4
foo5 bar5
foo6 bar6
foo7 bar7
foo8 bar8
foo9 bar9
foo10 bar10
```

Answer (score 1):

Building on [Hillsie’s answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/306787/80216#306841) to [this similar question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/306787/80216),
if you’re using bash, you can do

```
paste <(tr ' ' '\n' < foo.txt) <(tr ' ' '\n' < bar.txt)
```

using process substitution (`<(…)`) to translate the spaces in your files
to newlines.

Answer (score 1):

As an alternative to the transpose-and-combine approaches posted already, here's a combine-and-transpose approach:

```
$ cat foo.txt bar.txt | rs -T
foo1   bar1
foo2   bar2
foo3   bar3
foo4   bar4
foo5   bar5
foo6   bar6
foo7   bar7
foo8   bar8
foo9   bar9
foo10  bar10
```

Comment: @G-Man `rs` needs to be installed, it's not a built-in. It's available on Debian and FreeBSD.  It's also not UUOC because `cat` does exactly what it's supposed to - join two text files together here, and redirect that via pipe to `rs` that interprets each line as separate array.  The `< input.txt` way isn't the best in this particular case

Comment: Sorry, I need new glasses; for a moment I thought I saw only one filename there.